# Dispensing beers at two different pressures?

Tags: kegging, carbonation, techniques, equipment, serving

I'm working on getting a dual-tap kegerator.  Is it worth it to pay the extra to dispense two beers at two different pressures?  I can see dispensing a low-carbonation ESB and a high-carbonation weizen side-by-side, but I don't want to go overboard with the cost.

Comment: I'm now dispensing two beers at the same carbonation. Never been an issue, really, as I tend to brew in series (American, English, Lagers, Wheats) and similar beers tend to like similar carbonation levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, if you're going to go the distance and convert a fridge, you should do it right and get the dual regulator setup so you can dispense at different pressures.  That is, if cost isn't an issue.

Well, cost would certainly be an issue for me, and I'm still debating whether or not I should do this, or even bother with converting a fridge at all--the picnic tap works fine for me and quick disconnects make it easy to switch back and forth between my two kegs in the fridge.

I guess the question is, how often are you going to be pouring?  Do you have a lot of people who come over to drink?  If so, then it might be worth it.

I generally only pour only a few glasses a night, so switching between kegs is easy enough for me.  But I think that if I were going to convert the fridge into a kegerator, it'd be for the "coolness factor" and I'd want to go all out with all the bells and whistles--including separate regulators for each keg to ensure appropriate carbonation and dispensing pressures.

Just my $.02

Comment: Assuming cost is not an option, split it into a Nitro side and a CO2 side. Its always interesting to taste the difference in your ESB when you push it with Nitrogen instead of CO2. But then, I almost always have a stout on one tap and an ESB or IPA on the other...

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you dispense at different pressures, you can carbonate beers independently of your dispense pressure.  With a T off of one regulator you can gave your normal serving pressure, then you can use the other side for high pressure quick carbing if necessary on occasion.

If I had the funds I'd go with a dual stage set up just for the flexibility.

One other thing to think about though would be pouring stouts.  If you make stouts (or any style) that you want on nitrogen, maybe investing the money on a nitrogen hook up is a better investment.  Of course that would be more expensive because you'd need the stout faucet too.